# Views in Django 1.8

Tags: python-2.7, django-views, django-1.8

I am having trouble linking views to a basic HttpResponse in an ecommerce template I am building.

The error I am getting is 404 but after looking through here and what the docs say I am a little confused as to what I have missed,

**The Model**

```
   from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150)
    description = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    mod_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150)


class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150)
    description = models.TextField()
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='itemphotos')
    price_in_sterling = models.DecimalField(max_digits =6, decimal_places=2)
    available = models.BooleanField()
    instock = models.IntegerField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    mod_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

**My views.py**

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.http import HttpResponse

    def index(request):
        return HttpResponse("Hi, your view worked")

    def catagory(request):
        return HttpResponse("Hi, you are looking at the catagory landing page")

    def manufacturer(request):
        return HttpResponse("Hi, here you can shop by brand")

    def product(request):
        return HttpResponse("Hi, here you can search by product")
```

**My urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^productcatalog/', include('productcatalog.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

**My urls.py from the app produtcatalog**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^productcatalog/$', views.catagory, name='catagory'),
    url(r'^productcatalog/$', views.manufacturer, name='brand'),
    url(r'^productcatalog/$', views.product, name='products'),
]
```

I am sure the error is in the second urls.py file but can't seem to catch it.

Answer (score 0):

well I have another method for this

urls.py

`from views import product
urlpatterns=[url(r'^product/$', product)]`

views.py

`def product(request):
    view="""<html><head></head><body><p>something</p></body></html> """
    return HttpResponse(view)`

I don't remember if I used the render method but is really useful specially when you put variables inside a html page

Comment: I tried this Luis and I come up with the same error. I am trying to pass 3 classes from one model to 4 pages. one page linking to three separate pages . I will add the Model too maybe that will help

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same url for all the views functions. Try changing it.

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^productcatalog-1/$', views.catagory, name='catagory'),
url(r'^productcatalog-2/$', views.manufacturer, name='brand'),
url(r'^productcatalog-3/$', views.product, name='products'),
```

]